# Ultrasonic sound in Android

Tags: android

How can i listen to Ultrasonic sound in Android platform?

Comment: Other's opinion's to the contrary, I wouldn't be surprised if many devices at their highest sample rates can obtain uncompressed audio buffers containing components above the frequency limit of at least some adult's hearing, though perhaps with reduced response.  I once found an FFT waterfal spectral display app on the market, if you have some kind of high frequency source would be easy to play with that and see.  It is also of course possible that there are hardware or software filters that roll off well below say 15 KHz.

Answer (score 1):

Open http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k91QZIsSEu8. Crank up media volume.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the answer is no.

While mic ability/range might vary from one device to another, the compression technology used to store audio is consistent.  As storing "useless" inaudible data would be a waste of space, I'd wager that audio compression software will cheerfully *pitch* (ha!) anything outside our range of hearing.

I also suspect that microphones with a broader range would be more expensive than ones limited to our range.

Comment: One can get at data before it's been compressed, and most cheap microphone elements are sensitive to much higher frequencies than your ears are.  That doesn't mean there aren't intentional filters that prevent this, but the cited reasons are unlikely to apply.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I used AudioRecorder to listen to the Mic and calculated the frequency using Zero crossing.. FFT would be a better solution..